# File input "accept" attribute not recognising docx files

Tags: html, file-upload

The following code behaves differently on two different PC's using Chrome

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" >
```

On the first browser, we get the correct options in the file select dialogue:

[image]

On the second browser, the mime type doesnt seem to be recognised at all:

[image]

The second pc doesnt have MS Office installed on it. Could this somehow affect how the browser recognises this particular mime type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The second pc doesnt have MS Office installed on it. Could this somehow affect how the browser recognises this particular mime type?

Correct.

The mapping between MIME types and file-extensions is stored in the Windows registry section that contains file-extension registrations. When Office is installed it adds those mappings. Computers do not ship with a magically updated mapping of MIME types-to-file-extensions.

As a fallback, use file-extensions - which is all you need with an `<input type="file" />` because Office only has a small number of distinct file extensions:

```
<input type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
```